# How to change PVC size for statefulset with helm chart for new releases and preserve value for existing releases

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-statefulset

It is known that PVC resize for existing statefulsets is not possible yet https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/68737

Now, I have a helm chart with a statefulset and a PVC with 1GB size. When upgrading existing releases, I want to keep the existing value for the volume size, 1GB.

When installing new releases, I want to change the default to, let's say, 10GB.

How can I achieve this with the same chart, and only with default values (without providing custom values at install time) ?

I tried with:

```
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: data
    spec:
      accessModes: ["ReadWriteOnce"]
      resources:
        requests:
{{- if .Release.IsInstall }}
          storage: {{ .Values.storage.size }}
{{- end }}
```

which works for scratch installs, but then for an upgrade, the "storage" attribute is removed by helm and I am back to the same error:

```
Error: StatefulSet.apps "test" is invalid: spec: Forbidden: updates to statefulset spec for fields other than 'replicas', 'template', and 'updateStrategy' are forbidden
```

Is there a way to get/preserve the previous applied value from inside the helm template ?

Note that I'm on helm v2.

Scenario:

- I have a chart with versions: 1.0.0, 1.0.1
- For version 1.0.0 .Values.storage.size is 1GB
- For version 1.0.1 .Values.storage.size is 10GB
- I have an existing release, A, with chart version 1.0.0, so volume size 1GB
- With only default values defined in values.yaml, I want to be able to:

  - upgrade release A from chart version 1.0.0 to 1.0.1 while preserving the volume size (1GB)
  - install from scratch release B, with chart version 1.0.1, with volume size 10

Comment: I can't get the point when you said you want keep 1Gb for the current release but 10gb for new releases, because if you are updating the same chart installation helm will try to update everything that was modified. Could you please clarify and if possible post something to reproduce?

Comment: updated the question with a scenario, let me know if it helps.

Comment: Maybe a 'if' conditional to check the chart version can solve it. It works for you?

Comment: Not really, because I can only know the new chart version, the one that I want to upgrade to, not the chart used to install the first revision of the release. Because is the first revision of the release that actually set the volume size. Right ?